# Transform element vertically setting maximum distance

Tags: javascript, transform, translate

I am using this nice script to "slowly translate up" the 'img' element when scrolling down. It almost works as I want to. What I need is to limit the "translate up" to few pixels. As of now, the 'img' moves up by a 300% and when I scroll back to the top of the page the Google logo looks like is dropping down from the stars :)

Please let me know if this is possible.

Thanks.

Snippet:

```js
let last_known_scroll_position = 0;
let ticking = false;

function doSomething(scroll_pos) {
  // Do something with the scroll position
  document.querySelector('.parallax').style.transform = 'translateY(-' + (scroll_pos * .1) + '%)';
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;

  if (!ticking) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      doSomething(last_known_scroll_position);
      ticking = false;
    });

    ticking = true;
  }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  
  if ($(this).scrollTop() <= $(this).height()*0.1) {
    $('.parallax').removeClass('hide');   
}
  else {
    $('.parallax').addClass('hide');
};

  if ($(this).scrollTop() > $(this).height()*0.1) {
    $('.p2').addClass('hide');   
    $('.p3').removeClass('hide');
}
  else {
    $('.p2').removeClass('hide');
    $('.p3').addClass('hide');
};

  if ($(this).scrollTop() > $(this).height()*1.5) {
    $('.p2').removeClass('hide');
    $('.p3').addClass('hide');   
}
  else {
    $('.p3, .p3-text, .p3sottocntr').removeClass('hide');
};

  if ($(this).scrollTop() > $(this).height()*2.8) {
    $('.p3').addClass('hide');   
    $('.p3-text, .p3sottocntr, .p-main.p4-text').addClass('hidefoot');
}
  else {
    $('.p3-text, .p3sottocntr, .p-main.p4-text').removeClass('hidefoot');
};

});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
* { margin: 0;}
body {height: 400vh; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; font-family: MuseoSans_700;}
a {color: black; text-decoration: none;}
:root {
color-scheme: light dark;
supported-color-schemes: light dark;
}
/* ---------- FONTS ----------*/
@font-face {
font-family:'MuseoSans-100';
src: url('../fonts/MuseoSans-100.otf');
}
@font-face {
font-family:'MuseoSans_700';
src: url('../fonts/MuseoSans_700.otf');
}
/* ---------- NERO ----------*/
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
html, body {background-color: rgb(18, 15, 15);}
.logo-p1 {background-color: rgb(18, 15, 15) !important;}
.logo-p1 svg {filter: invert(1) }
.logo-p1 svg:hover {padding-left: -410px;padding-left: 441px;}
}
/* ---------- SCROLLBAR ----------*/
body, html {
scrollbar-face-color: ThreeDFace !important;
scrollbar-shadow-color: ThreeDDarkShadow !important;
scrollbar-highlight-color: ThreeDHighlight !important;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: ThreeDLightShadow !important;
scrollbar-darkshadow-color: ThreeDDarkShadow !important;
scrollbar-track-color: Scrollbar !important;
scrollbar-arrow-color: ButtonText !important;
}
/* .parallax::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
}
.parallax::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background: transparent;
}
.parallax::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background: transparent;
visibility:hidden;
border-top: 13px solid black;
}
.parallax:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
visibility:visible;*/
.parallax::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
}
.parallax::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background: transparent
}
.parallax::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background: transparent;
border-top: 8px solid black;
}
.parallax:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
visibility:visible;
background: transparent;
border-top: 13px solid black;
}
/* ---------- LOGO ----------*/
.logo-p1 {
overflow: hidden;
border: 0px solid red;
width: 440px;
height: 45px;
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
top: calc(50vh - 22.5px);
left: calc(50% - 220px);
margin: 0;
}
.logo-p1 svg {left: -442px;position: absolute;width: 880px;-webkit-transform: scale(1); transform: scale(1)}
.logo-p1 svg:hover {left: 0px;position: absolute;width: 880px;-webkit-transform: scale(1); transform: scale(1)}
.logo-p2, .logo-p3 {left: 0;overflow: hidden; border: 0px solid red;width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: white; position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 40px; margin: 0;}
.logo-p2 svg {margin-left: -100px}
.logo-p2 svg:hover {margin-left: 0px}
.logo-p3 svg {margin-left: 0px}
.logo-p3 svg:hover {margin-left: -100px}
/* ---------- PREFOOT ----------*/
.prefoot {}
/* ---------- PARALLAX ----------*/
.parallax {
perspective: 1px;
height: calc(100vh * 1 - 0px);
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
position: fixed;
background: white;
z-index: 2;
padding: 0vh 0 0vh 0;
width: 100%;
opacity: 1;
transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
.parallax.hide {
opacity: 0;
transition: all 1s ease;

}

.parallax.relat {
perspective: 1px;
height: 100vh;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
}
.object-wrapper {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: none;
justify-content: center;
}
.speed-1 {transform: translateZ(-6.1px) scale(7);}
/* ---------- SECTIONS ----------*/
.p1 {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
display: inline-grid;
z-index: 3;
background: white;
opacity: 1;
transition: all 0.8s ease;
/* margin: 90vh 0 0vh 0; */
}
.p1.hide {
opacity: 0;
transition: all 1.4s ease;
visibility: hidden;
}
.p2 {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
display: block;
z-index: 2;
top: 0vh;
background: white;
visibility: hidden;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
opacity: 0;
}
.p2.hide {
opacity: 1;
transition: all 1.4s ease;
visibility: visible;
}
.p3 {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
display: block;
z-index: 2;
top: 0vh;
background: white;
visibility: hidden;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
opacity: 0;
}
.p3.hide {
opacity: 1;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
visibility: visible;
}
.p-main.p4-text.hidefoot {
width: 100%;
height: 250px;
background-color: black;
/* position: relative; */
left: 0px;
margin: auto;
bottom: 250px;
}
.p-main.p4-text {
width: 100%;
height: 0px;
background-color: black;
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
margin: auto;
bottom: 0px;
clip-path: polygon(0 40%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 40%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
transition: all 0.9s;
transform: translateY(250px);
transform-origin: bottom;
}
.p4 {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
display: block;
z-index: -1;
}
.p4.hidefoot {
opacity: 1;
transition: all 0.9s ease;
visibility: visible;
}
/* ---------- TESTO SECTIONS ----------*/
.p-main {
width: 355px;
height: 230px;
background-color: transparent;
position: fixed;
bottom: 40px;
left: 40px;
margin: 0;
display: flex;
justify-content: left;
align-items: flex-end;
border: 0px solid red;
filter: invert(0);
font-family: MuseoSans-100;
font-size: 13px;
font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.p3-text {
opacity: 1;
transition: all 0.9s ease;
visibility: visible;
}
.p3-text.hidefoot {
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.9s ease;
visibility: hidden;
}
.p-desc {line-height: 16px;}
.p-desc b {font-family: MuseoSans_700;font-weight: normal;}
.p-col {margin-top: 20px;column-count: 2;line-height: 16px;"><font style="font-family: MuseoSans_700;}

/* ---------- MENU SOTTO ----------*/

.sottocentro {
width: 250px;
height: 140px;
background-color: transparent;
position: fixed;
bottom: 40px;
right: calc(0% - 0px);
margin: 0;
display: -webkit-box;
justify-content: center;
align-items: flex-end;
filter: invert(0);
font-family: MuseoSans-100;
font-size: 13px;
font-smoothing: antialiased;
border: 0px solid red;
right: 40px;
}

.p3sottocntr {
opacity: 1;
transition: all 0.9s ease;
visibility: visible;
}
.p3sottocntr.hidefoot {
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.9s ease;
visibility: hidden;
}


.sottocentro ul {
list-style: none;
text-align: right;
width: auto;
border: 0px solid red;
line-height: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
clear: both;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px;
right: 40px;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
}

.sottocentro ul li {
    border: none;
    text-align: right;
    width: auto;
}

.sottocentro ul li.begins {
border: none;
text-align: right;
width: auto;
padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.sottocentro ul li.sottoc-bold {

    font-family: MuseoSans_700;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parallax">
        <section class="p1 speed-1">
            <div class="logo-p1">
                <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2021/doodle-champion-island-games-august-24-6753651837108999-s.png">
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <section class="p2">
        <div class="logo-p2">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2021/doodle-champion-island-games-august-24-6753651837108999-s.png">
        </div>
        <div class="p-main p2-text">
            <div>
                <p class="p-desc p2-desc"> <b>Lorem ipsum </b>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum..
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="p3">
        <div class="logo-p3">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2021/doodle-champion-island-games-august-24-6753651837108999-s.png">
        </div>
        <div class="p-main p3-text">
            <div>
                <p class="p-desc p3-desc"> <b>Sed ut perspiciatis </b>unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
</body>
</html>

<script>

document.querySelector('.parallax').addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.p1, .p2').addClass('hide');
   } else {
    $('.p1, .p2').removeClass('hide');
   }
});

document.querySelector('.parallax').addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1200) {
    $('.p3').addClass('hide');
    $('.p2').removeClass('hide');
   } else {
    $('.p3').removeClass('hide');
   }
});

document.querySelector('.parallax').addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1800) {
    $('.p3-text, .p3sottocntr, .p-main.p4-text').addClass('hidefoot');
   } else {
    $('.p3-text, .p3sottocntr, .p-main.p4-text').removeClass('hidefoot');
   }
});

/// Scroll back to top
$("a[href='.parallax']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;
});

</script>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what this nice script is intended for-- could you provide an explanation?  Even better, a working [mcve] snippet in the question body would _really_ lower the level of effort for a visitor to the page to try to help you solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry you are right, I have added a Codepen: https://codepen.io/sinetempore/pen/ZEyYVxo
Basically when you scroll all the way down and then scroll all the way up, the Google logo looks like is dropping down from -100000px.... I only need to Google logo to move up few px...

Comment: A link to a codepen can be interesting, but your question should have all information to understand the issue. Include a runnable snippet using the editor toolbar.

Comment: What happened to the previous comments?

Comment: I _believe_ that sometimes comments are removed at moderators' discretion; I am not certain of the criteria by which they determine which to remove.